# Creating new SQL Connection Error

Tags: c#, winforms

As you probably know, to create a new connection to a DataBase we use the command:

```
 con = new SqlConnection(string connectionString);
```

However my connection string already has the quotation marks ( these symbols " "). So when I type:

```
con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Mike\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Concurs\Concurs\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True");
```

I get this error:

> Unexpected character '\'

And this error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

So what do I do to get rid of these errors?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape your quote characters by doubling them:

```
con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\Mike\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Concurs\Concurs\Database1.mdf"";Integrated Security=True");
```

That way the compiler knows you aren't terminating your string literal but are instead intending to have the quote characters included *in* the literal.